# Proof that Hecke operators on modular forms commute

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I am working on Hecke operators on modular forms and would like to prove that these commute. Specifically, I am trying to prove that
$$
T_nT_m=\sum_{d\vert (n, m)} d^{k-1} T_{\frac{nm}{d^2}}=T_mT_n,
$$
where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the gcd.

The proof is a computation and I end up having to justify the equality
$$
\sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\sum_{d\vert (m, \alpha)} d^{k-1} \sum_{a\vert (n, \frac{m\alpha}{d^2})} a^{k-1} c\left(\frac{mn\alpha}{d^2a^2}\right)\right)q^\alpha =\sum_{d\vert (n, m)} d^{k-1}\sum_{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\sum_{a\vert (\frac{nm}{d^2}, \alpha)} a^{k-1} c\left(\frac{mn\alpha}{d^2a^2}\right)\right)q^\alpha
$$ 
and this is twisting my mind. Here, $c(n)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fourier coefficient of the modular form $f$ and $q=q(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$. Hopefully someone can explain why this equality holds.

Thank you.

Comment: Try doing the case where $m$ and $n$ are distinct primes first.

Comment: That would be of the same difficulty as doing the case where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, would it not ? I don't see how doing that case would help me solve my original problem.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at my answer in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821347/how-to-prove-t-mt-n-sum-d-gcdm-ndk-1t-mn-d2-t-n-is-hecke/2843374#2843374