# How to prove $T_{m}T_{n}=\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)}d^{k-1}T_{mn/d^2}?$ $T_{n}$ is Hecke operator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

> Define Hecke operator is $$T_{n}: M_{k}(\Gamma(1))\rightarrow  M_{k}(\Gamma(1))$$ 
>   $$ T_{n}: f \longmapsto n^{k-1}\sum_{a,d>0, ad=n}\sum_{b=0}^{d-1} d^{-k}f(\frac{a\tau+b}{d}).$$
>   How to prove $T_{m}T_{n}=\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)}d^{k-1}T_{mn/d^2}?$

I have proved that $$(T_{n}f)(\tau)=\sum_{a,d>0, ad=n}\Big(\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)}d^{k-1} a\big(\frac{mn}{d^2}\big)\Big)q^m$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is rather technical. Here we show the multiplicative property of the Hecke operators by following mostly verbatim Theorem 6.12 and 6.13 of T. M. Apostol's *[Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387971270)*.

The  proof is organised in two parts. First it is shown for positive integers $m,n$ relatively prime and then for prime powers.

> **First part (Theorem 6.12):** If $m,n$ are positive integers with $(m,n)=1$ the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> T_nT_m=T_{mn}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

If $f\in M_k$ we have
\begin{align*}
(T_nf)(\tau)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{{a\ge 1,ad=n}\atop{0\leq b<d}}a^kf(A\tau)
\end{align*}
where $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}$. Applying $T_m$ to each member we have
\begin{align*}
\{T_m(T_n(f))\}(\tau)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{{\alpha\geq 1,\alpha\delta=m}\atop{0\leq \beta<\delta}}
\alpha^k\frac{1}{n}\sum_{{a\geq 1,ad=m}\atop{0\leq b<d}}a^kf(BA\tau)
\end{align*}
where $B=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\0&\delta\end{pmatrix}$. This can  be written as
\begin{align*}
\{T_m(T_n(f))\}(\tau)=\frac{1}{mn}\sum_{{\alpha\geq 1,\alpha\delta=m}\atop{0\leq \beta<\delta}}
\sum_{{a\geq 1,ad=m}\atop{0\leq b<d}}(\alpha a)^kf(C\tau)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
C=BA=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\0&\delta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha a&\alpha b+\beta d\\0&d\delta\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
As $d$ and $\delta$ run through the positive divisors of $n$ and $m$, respectively, the product $d\delta$ runs through the positive divisors of $mn$ since $(m,n)=1$. The linear combination $\alpha b+\beta d$ runs through a complete residue system mod $d\delta$ as $b$ and $\beta$ run through complete residue systems mod $d$ and $\delta$, respectively. Therefore the matrix $C$ runs through a complete set of non-equivalent elements of $\Gamma(mn)$ and we see that (2) implies (1).

> **Second part (Theorem 6.13):** Any two Hecke operators $T(n)$ an $T(m)$ defined on $M_k$ commute with each other. Moreover, we have the composition formula
>   \begin{align*}
> T(m)T(n)=\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^{k-1}T(mn/d^2)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

If $(m,n)=1$ the formula (3) reduces to (1). Therefore it suffices to treat the case when $m$ and $n$ are powers of the same prime $p$. First we consider the case $m=p$ and $n=p^r$, where $r \geq 1$. In this case we are to prove that
\begin{align*}
T(p)T(p^r)=T(p^{r+1})+p^{k-1}T(p^{r-1})
\end{align*}
Using the representation
\begin{align*}
(T(n)f)(\tau)=n^{k-1}\sum_{{a\geq 1,ad=n}\atop{0\leq b<d}}d^{-k}f\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{d}\right)
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{{a\geq 1,ad=n}\atop{0\leq b<d}}a^k f\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{d}\right)\tag{4}
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
\{T(p^r)f\}(\tau)=p^{-r}\sum_{{0\leq t\leq r}\atop{0\leq b_t<p^t}}p^{(r-t)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r-t}\tau+b_t}{p^t}\right)\tag{5}
\end{align*}
From the representation
\begin{align*}
(T(n)f)(\tau)=n^{k-1}\sum_{d|n}d^{-k}\sum_{b=0}^{d-1}f\left(\frac{n\tau+bd}{d^2}\right)
\end{align*}
we have in the special case when $n$ is prime, say $n=p$
\begin{align*}
(T(p)f)(\tau)=p^{k-1}f(p\tau)+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}f\left(\frac{\tau+b}{p}\right)
\end{align*}
and so when we apply $T(p)$ to each member of (5) we find
\begin{align*}
\{T(p)T(p^r)f\}(\tau)&=p^{k-1-r}\sum_{{0\leq t\leq r}\atop{0\leq b_t<p^t}}p^{(r-t)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r+1-t}\tau+pb_t}{p^t}\right)\\
&\qquad +p^{-1-r}\sum_{{0\leq t\leq r}\atop{0\leq b_t<p^t}}p^{(r-t)k}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}f\left(\frac{p^{r-t}\tau+b_t+bp^t}{p^{t+1}}\right)
\end{align*}
In the second sum the linear combination $b_t+bp^t$ runs through a complete residue system mod $p^{t+1}$. Since $r-t=(r+1)-(t+1)$ the second sum, together with the term $t=0$ from the first sum, is equal to $\{T(p^{r+1}f\}(\tau)$. In the remaining terms we cancel a factor $p$ in the argument of $f$, then transfer the facctor $p^k$ to each summand to obtain
\begin{align*}
\{T(p)T(p^r)f\}(\tau)=\{T(p^{r+1})f\}(\tau)+p^{-1-r}\sum_{{1\leq t\leq r}\atop{0\leq b_t<p^t}}p^{(r+1-t)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r-t}\tau+b_t}{p^{t-1}}\right).
\end{align*}
Dividing each $b_t$ b $p^{t-1}$ we can write
\begin{align*}
b_t=q_tp^{t-1}+r_t
\end{align*}
where $0\leq r_t<p^{t-1}$ and $q_t$ runs through a complete residue system mod $p$. Since $f$ is periodic with period $1$ we have
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{p^{r-t}\tau+b_t}{p^{t-1}}\right)=f\left(\frac{p^{r-t}\tau+r_t}{p^{t-1}}\right),
\end{align*}
so as $q_t$ runs through a complete residue system mod $p$ each term is repeated $p$ times. Replacing the index $t$ by $t-1$ we see the last sum is $p^{k-1}$ times the sum defining $\{T(p^{r-1})f\}(\tau)$. This proves (4).

The last step is to consider general powers of the same prime, say $m=p^s$ and $n=p^r$. Assuming without loss of generality that $r\leq s$ it can be shown by induction on $r$ that
\begin{align*}
T(p^r)T(p^s)=\sum_{t=0}^rp^{t(k-1)}T(p^{r+s-2t})=\sum_{d|(p^r,p^s)}d^{k-1}T\left(\frac{p^{r+s}}{d^2}\right)
\end{align*}
for all $r$ and all $s\geq r$ and the claim (3) follows.

> **Note:** It might be interesting to note that *[multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)*  arithmetic functions $f$ which share the property corresponding to (3) are called *specially multiplicative functions*.

According to *[Introduction to Arithmetical Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038796262X)* by P. J. McCarthy we have:

> If $f$ is a multiplicative function then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ is a convolution of two completely multiplicative functions.
> - There is a multiplicative function $F$ such that for all $m$ and $n$,
>     \begin{align*}
>   f(mn)=\sum_{d|(m,n)}f\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)F(d)
>   \end{align*}
> - There is a completely multiplicative function $B$ such that for all $m$ and $n$
>     \begin{align*}
>   f(m)f(n)=\sum_{d|(m,n)}f\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right)B(d)
>   \end{align*}
> - For all primes $p$ and all $r \geq 1$,
>     \begin{align*}
>   f(p^{r+1})=f(p)f(p^r)+f(p^{r-1})\left(f(p^2)-f(p)^2\right)
>   \end{align*}

Prominent members of this function class are the *[divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)* $\sigma_k$ fulfilling the so-called *Busche-Ramanujan identity*
\begin{align*}
\sigma_k(m)\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^k\sigma_k\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right)
\end{align*}
and the *[Ramanujan Tau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function)* with
\begin{align*}
\tau(m)\tau(n)=\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^{11}\tau\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui: Thanks a lot for accepting the answer and granting the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f=\sum_{m=0} ^{\infty} a(m)q^m$ be a Fourier expansion of $f\in M_k(\Gamma(1))$, then we have:
    \begin{equation}(1) \ \ \ 
T_n f=\sum_{m=0} ^{\infty} \left(\sum_{d|(n,m)} d^{k-1}a\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right)\right)q^m .
\end{equation}
    Let $b(l)$ denote the $l$-th Fourier coefficient of $T_n T_m f$. Then, by (1),
    \begin{equation}(2) \ \ \ 
b(l)=\sum_{\substack{{d|n}\\{d|l}}} d^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{{e|m}\\{e|{\frac{nl}{d^2}}}}} e^{k-1} a\left(\frac{mnl}{d^2 e^2}\right).
\end{equation}
    On the other hand, the $l$-th Fourier coefficient $c(l)$ of $\sum_{u|(n,m)} u^{k-1} T_{\frac{mn}{u^2}}f$ is
    \begin{equation} (3) \ \ \ 
c(l)=\sum_{\substack{{u|n}\\{u|m}}} u^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{{v|l}\\{v|{\frac{mn}{u^2}}}}} v^{k-1} a\left(\frac{mnl}{u^2 v^2}\right).
\end{equation}
    Consider a change of variable in (2) with 
$$
(4) \ \ \ u=\frac {e(d,\frac me)}{(e,\frac ld)},  \ \ v=\frac{(e,\frac ld)d}{(d,\frac me)}.
$$

This is an invertible mapping between the sets of pairs $(d,e)$ in (2) and $(u,v)$ in (3).

Hence, $b(l)=c(l)$ as desired. Then it completes the proof of 
$$
T_nT_m=\sum_{u|(n,m)} u^{k-1} T_{\frac{mn}{u^2}}.
$$

To see that the change of variable (4) is invertible, we have to show that $(u,v)$ in (4) satisfy the conditions in (3) under the assumptions of $(d,e)$ in (2). This can be shown by
$u|e \frac me = m$, $u| \frac nd(d,\frac me) | n$, $v|\frac ld d = l$, 
$$
u^2 v = \frac{e^2 (d,\frac me)^2}{(e,\frac ld)^2} \frac{(e,\frac ld)d}{(d,\frac me)}=\frac{e^2(d,\frac me) d}{(e,\frac ld)}=ude \Bigg\vert n(d,\frac me) e \Bigg\vert n \frac me e = nm.
$$

Also, the same procedure 
$$
(5) \ \ \ d=\frac{v(u,\frac lv)}{(v,\frac mu)}, \ \ e=\frac{(v,\frac mu) u}{(u,\frac lv)},
$$
takes the pairs $(u,v)$ in (3) to $(d,e)$ in (2).

Moreover, the change of variables (4) and (5) are in fact inverse of each other, since 
$$
\frac{(u,\frac lv)}{(v,\frac mu)} = \frac{\left( \frac{e(d,\frac me)}{(e,\frac ld)}, \frac{(d,\frac me)l}{(e,\frac ld)d}\right)}{\left(\frac{(e,\frac ld)d}{(d,\frac me)},\frac{(e,\frac ld) m}{(d,\frac me)e}\right)}=\frac{(d,\frac me)}{(e,\frac ld)}.
$$

Note that this is essentially interchanging places of $l$ and $m$ in (2). Since places of $n$ and $l$ can be interchanged, the whole problem is equivalent to the result $T_mT_n = T_nT_m$.

The change of variable (4) is not easy to see. However, (4) becomes a lot easier if we impose $(m,n)=1$. So, an alternative method is to derive $T_{mn}=T_mT_n$ when $(m,n)=1$, then prove that $T_{p^s}$ is expressed as a polynomial of $T_p$.